# MovieFinishedCallback notification not firing

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to create an app that displays an info page once a video stops playing. I've looked at a similar question posted here and tried to implement it but it still doesn't work. I put an NSLog in the movieFinishedCallback method but that never came up so I'm guessing it doesn't even get called. Can someone help me figure it out?

Here's my implementation code...

```
-(IBAction)playvideo {


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                     initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:playercontroller];



    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;


    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];


    playercontroller = nil;

} 


- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) notification {

  NSLog (@"The video ended");

  MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];    
    player = nil;


    View2 *second =[[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY made it work! I don't know if it has to do with the fact that MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't respond to the NSNotificationCenter but I used MPMoviePlayerController instead to display my video, registered the notification for movieFinishedCallback and then used the movieFinishedCallback method to switch views. See this tutorial for video play http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Application. Only thing is, now the video won't rotate to landscape!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably getting called back when movie is finished, but failing when presenting View2.

Is View2 a subclass of UIViewController?  I can't see how you'll get a valid result by passing nil to initWithNibName:.  I'd suggest an NSLog in movieFinishedCallback to prove you get there.  Then NSLog(@"second = %@", second);  My guess is that's nil.

The fix is to load a view controller for real, either using a valid nib or from your storyboard...

```
// @"MainStoryboard" should be the name of the storyboard containing your VC
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

// @"SomeViewController" has to be set on the attributes inspector of the VC
// in the storyboard
SomeViewController *newVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks @danh! Yes, View2 is a subclass of UIViewController. I tried adding an NSLog in movieFinishedCallback and it didn't show up so it's probably not getting called. The video plays fine but I'm also getting multiple..." Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/..." and at the end it says Cannot find function pointer NewDigiCoreAudioPlugIn for factory.... (bundle, not loaded). Please help?

Comment: I think you can ignore those error msgs on playback. Widely reported simulator issue. Need to think about getting called on the notifications.  Can you see if you can get loadstatechanged notifications?

Comment: that's not logging anything either. :(